# parse a text file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, awk, sed

I am running a hadoop command and saving the output to a txt file. I just want a specific part of the hadoop command to be in the text file.

```
#!/bin/sh

hadoop fs -ls /projects/abcd/ | egrep 'delta|snapshot' > /homes/abcd/tools/list_of_feeds.txt
```

The contents of 'list_of_feeds.txt' -

```
drwxr-x---   - abcd users                  0 2013-02-05 12:16 /projects/abcd/test1_delta
drwxr-x---   - abcd users                  0 2013-02-06 00:21 /projects/abcd/test2_snapshot
```

I just want the contents of the file to be -

```
test1_delta
test2_snapshot
```

how do i parse this file or do this in shell?

Thanks

Comment: Your `for` loop is wacky. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: well i wrote the for loop to try to parse the text file for the output i want...$10 is wrong there... @ooga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is useful (and easy) for selecting fields.

```
hadoop fs -ls /projects/abcd/ | awk -F '/' '/delta|snapshot/ {print $NF}' > /homes/abcd/tools/list_of_feeds.txt
```

I have no idea what your for loop is doing, however.

`$NF` selects the last field since it would be kind of stupid to hardcode the number of components in the pathname.

And obviously `egrep` is unnecessary in conjunction with `awk`.

Comment: Nice, I got it man. Yes, the for loop was a lame attempt - was trying out options. I am just starting to learn awk.

Answer (score -1):

You can pipe your command into awk. Use the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

hadoop fs -ls /projects/abcd/ | egrep 'delta|snapshot' | awk -F '/' '{print $4} > /homes/abcd/tools/list_of_feeds.txt 
cat /homes/abcd/tools/list_of_feeds.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, had to edit that a few times since I put the ask in the wrong place, but that should work. Otherwise, let me know.

Comment: Ya, I just copied his syntax and inserted the awk. Adjusted it to work correctly.

Comment: In what sense does it "work correctly"? Did you even test it?

Comment: Indeed I did. Based on the output his command is already printing. I tested myself that the awk would parse out the specific info he wanted.

Comment: @Stephen - i guess this will not work...and plus egrep and awk would not work in conjunction..but thanks for posting.

Comment: sure thing mate. egrep and awk would work in conjunction, but as @ooga pointed out, there would really be no point to. Glad you got what ya needed.